# Ruby Code Not Working

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos, ubuntu

I've inherited some code from a coworker, the catch being I haven't done coding before.  This code works on my machine, and other machines.  However when I attempt to run it on a new system with newly installed Ruby and the dependent gems, it doesn't preform as expected.  So this code DOES work... just not on all our systems.  And I'm too unfamiliar to know what exactly to look for to find the inconsistency.

If anyone has an idea or any tips on how I can solve this, I'd be extremely grateful.

```
require 'curb' # For Curl statement
require 'nokogiri' # for screen scrapping
require 'io/console' # hide password input
require 'mechanize' # clicking through and logging in

#start your engines
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.keep_alive = false
agent.open_timeout   = 180
agent.read_timeout   = 180
page  = agent.get('http://_____.co.__________.com/admin/_____/user/')

#get login for _____
puts "Please enter your _____ Login:"
prompt = '>'
print prompt
page.forms.first.fields[1].value =  STDIN.gets.chomp()
puts "Please enter your password:"
print prompt
#this way keeps you from seeing the password on the screen
page.forms.first.fields[2].value =  STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp()
puts "Searching for %s" % ARGV[0]
#click the login button
login_page = page.forms.first.submit    
#take the first argument and put it in the user search box
login_page.forms.first.fields.first.value = ARGV[0]
#click search
users_page = login_page.forms.first.submit
#click on the only link, people with "deleted" account might need some hacking to make work
inventory_page = users_page.links.last.click
puts "Found %s, now opening user page..." % ARGV[0]
active_inventory = []
puts "checking total active inventorys..."
#find the inventory table and get all the rows. Then loop through and check if active. If active put FSID into an array to check next
inventory_page.parser.xpath('//tr[contains(@id,"filesystemproperties")]').each do |row|  
#inventory_page.parser.css('tr.has_original').each do |row|     
    if row.at('img')["alt"] == "True"
        active_inventory << row.children[2].text.gsub("\n",'').strip
        puts row.children[2].text.gsub("\n",'').strip
    end
end

#now lets send a inventory, go to the inventory Versions link at the top of the page
get_inventory = inventory_page.links[3].click

#require 'logger' #debug stuff, pay no attention.
#agent.log = Logger.new $stderr
#agent.agent.http.debug_output = $stderr
puts "checking total size of inventorys..."

#time for some simple addition
inventory_size = 0
#clear out any blank fsid, then each one send (POST)
active_inventory.reject!(&:empty?).each do |fsid|
    get_inventory.forms.first.fields.first.value = fsid
    size = get_inventory.forms.first.submit
    #get the top row second column for latest size, and add it to the existing tally for total size
    inventory_size += size.parser.xpath('//tbody/tr[1]/td[2]').text.to_i
    puts "%s is %d Bytes" % [fsid, size.parser.xpath('//tbody/tr[1]/td[2]').text.to_i]
    puts "current inventory: #{inventory_size}"
    #sleep 15
end
#convert those bytes to MEGABytes
puts "%d currently active inventory(s) found\n" % (active_inventory.count - 3)
puts "\n \n \nTotal inventory size is: %f MB" % [inventory_size/(1024*1024).to_f]
```

You can see the output in the attached images.  **Purple** background is working, **white** background is busted.  I've also had the same unsuccessful results on an Ubuntu VM

**Works:** OS X 10.8.5; Ruby 2.1.1; XCODE 5.1.1
**Doesn't work:** OS X 10.8.5 (VirtualBox); Ruby 2.1.1; XCODE 5.1.1
**Doesn't work:** Ubuntu 14.04 (VirualBox); Ruby 2.1.2; XCODE n/a

[image]

[image]

Comment: I appreciate that you've put some work into asking this, but this is pretty hard to answer based just off a surface description. It's not like there's a "work correctly" button everyone knows you're supposed to be pushing and you just aren't. This looks like the sort of problem where I'd get hands-on — break out a logger/debugger and try to figure out where the environments are diverging. A few obvious things to look at would be gem versions on the systems and differences in networks (since this appears to operate over the network).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that a difference in environments, specifically with the gems, is causing inconsistent behavior. On each environment, try a

```
gem list
```

Look for the gems this script requires, and look for different version numbers between the different environments. If you do need different versions, you can do the following:

```
gem uninstall <gem-name>
gem install <gem-name> -v <desired-version-number>
```

Comment: HA!  Thanks Redyaffle, that did it!  The newer installs simply had a more recent version of one of the gems.  Uninstalling the new one and installing the "old" snapped it into place like a champ.